# test arima model

Tags: r, statistics

I am validating Arima models and I would like to know the critical value of my test to reject the null hypthesis depending on the p-value. If a want a confidence of 95%. which is my critical value.

```
1-pchisq(-2*(try2$loglik-try1$loglik),1)
 0.1817151
1-pchisq(-2*(try3$loglik-try2$loglik),1)
1
```

Where try1, try2 and try3 are three different models.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cross validation for ARIMA (AutoRegressive Integrated Moving Average) time series:** K-fold cross validation does not work for time-series. Instead, use backtesting techniques like [walk-forward](https://community.darwinex.com/t/walk-forward-optimization-for-machine-learning-in-python/3769) and [rolling windows](https://www.quantstart.com/articles/Backtesting-a-Moving-Average-Crossover-in-Python-with-pandas).

**K-fold cross-validation for autoregression:** Although cross-validation is (usually) not valid for time series (ARIMA) models, K-fold works for autoregressions as long as the models considered have uncorrelated errors, and you have tested it with the [Ljung Box Test](https://www.revolvy.com/page/Ljung%E2%80%93Box-test), for XAI (Explainable Artificial Intelligence) in time series use cases.

- There are a few Python statistics libs that have these methods avail, 
  here are two: [Python Stats Tests](http://pypr.sourceforge.net/stattest.html) and [Python StatsModels](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html).
- You can always study the Python APIs and refactor into R quite easily.

To get the diff of values, you can simply enforce int8's using [Python 3.6+ PEP 487 Descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-487-descriptor-protocol-enhancements), where you can enforce a type list that always returns int8's, for faster computation as well (list : list -> list of ints):

```
list_a = [1,2,3]
list_b = [2,3]
print(set(list_a).difference(set(list_b)))
```

answer is `set([1])`

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a little bit more info, but I think I see what you're trying to do.

Your null hypothesis is that the two models do not provide the same goodness of fit - one model is not "better" than another. Generally, you test each model against a baseline model. The interpretation of your results is this: none of the models are significantly different (at a 5% significance level).

By using 1 degree of freedom, you imply that a single independent variable is added in each model. For example, `try1` has 1 independent variable, `try2` has 2, and `try3` has 3. Also keep in mind that you absolutely must have the same dependent variable for this to be valid.

Comment: I am trying to look for the difference between an (2,1,1) and (1,1,1) arima model. That's why my degree of freedom is 1. What I need to know is for which values I stay with try1 or try2 in the first case. Thanks