# Building a Arima model in python

Tags: datetime, time-series, statsmodels, timeserieschart

I have just started to study about the ARIMA models and I am trying to model a variable for which I have plotted the series, auto-correlation and partial auto-correlation(with a 95% confidence bands) and have run the augmented dickey fuller test. I am using `statsmodels` package in python3.

The variable gives a positive augmented dickey fuller test, so it is stationary but the plot shows clearly that there is increasing trend. Thus, there is contradiction.

How can I check whether the variable is stationary or not?
And what other steps should I take before I start modelling?

The plots are included below:

[image: The target variable plot]

[image: Auto-correlation plot]

[image: Partial Auto-correlation plot]

Comment: Sharing relevant pieces of your code will help people help you.

Comment: it is more of a visualization problem then a coding problem.

Comment: See my answer here:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15880278/test-arima-model/54022502#54022502](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15880278/test-arima-model/54022502#54022502)